# Creat a view that like add library used in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstableview, nsview

I need to create a view to display product information in multiple rows, and user can click add or remove button to operate each row,if new row added,the view will automatically increase, this is most like a view used in xCode to manage library, is there anyone can give me some advise or a example. thanks ！

a snap shot of the view I want to create :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

simple answer : use a `UITableView` or `NSTableView`, add an entry to the datasource and reload it when you need to add content, have a look at

iOS : [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/).

OSX : [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/)

Comment: yes,thanks! NSTableView can show only parts of rows,and more rows need to scroll to bottom, i dont need a scroller,you can see in my snapshot,there is no scroller,if i added a row,the view will automatically increase and so its superview.

Comment: increase the NSTableView itself according to the number of cells, by that there would be no scrolling, and it will behave like you mentioned, tableHeight = rowHeight*numberOfRows.

Comment: @DeyaEldeen NSTableView is automatically resized when the number or rows changes. The enclosing scroll view has to be resized.